# Best Practice: Copy a file at a certain time?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, scripting, copy

I've been wrangled into the world of Windows system administration. Coming from a Linux sysadmin background, I am looking for the best way to copy a file to a directory at a specific time. (Change management requires us to copy the file in a certain window of time.) I know Windows has a Task Scheduler. Is that the best tool to use to copy my file?

Using Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use it exclusively in Windows to schedule tasks, mainly because Windows systems never seem to have any set of "standard" tools that admins install. Windows Scheduled Tasks Manager does the job. It has a command line utility as well and you can count on it being installed on every machine. I say it's the best bet, but would love to hear other opinions.

Just make sure your service accounts have the rights you need. The windows default service accounts typically have ZERO network access capabilities, so if your copy is across network shares you could be screwed.

Comment: I actually feel the exact same way about Linux boxen - I find they never have a standard set of tools either.

Answer (score 1):

[Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx) and the windows scheduler will do that just fine. Also be sure that the time is properly set and synchronised on the servers if they 're not part of an active directory domain.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a scheduled to task to run a .bat file at a certain time would probably suffice.  As JS mentioned, make sure your account has the correct permissions to copy the file and to write inside the folder that you are copying it to.